# Loop over dictionary of dictionaries in Django Template for 1 line of code

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, dictionary

The dictionary I'm passing to the Django template contains 2 dictionaries, each with a list:

```
'nav_dict': {
                'class_name': ['Chemical', 'Avian', 'Mammal'],
                'tab_label': ['Chemical!', 'Avian!', 'Mammal!']
                }
```

I want to loop over the lists in each dict to fill out this line of code:

```
<li class="{{ item_className }} tabSel">{{ item_tabLabel }}</li>
```

where `item_className` = each value in the class_name list and `item_tabLabel` = each value in the tab_label list.  The result would 3 `<li>` tags with a `class_name` and `tab_label`.

I have tried something like this (This code only handles the `class_name` part), but I can't get the loops to append to the same line of code (each `<li>`):

```
{% for key, value in nav_dict.items %}
        {% if key == 'class_name' %}

            {% for item_className in value %}
                {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}
                    <li class="{{ item_className }} tabSel">{{ item_tabLabel }}</li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="{{ item_className }} tabUnsel">{{ item_tabLabel }}</li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: what do you mean by same line of code ?

Comment: The "!" added to the end of second list items is only a place holder showing that the two lists are different.  This is because the first list is CSS class names and the second list is how they would appear on the web page. E.g. `class="WaterBody"` would be "Water Body"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *have to* use that dictionary, you can use this template code:

```
{% for item_className in nav_dict.class_name %}
  {% with forloop.counter0 as index_className %}
    {% for item_tabLabel in nav_dict.tab_label %}
      {% with forloop.counter0 as index_tabLabel %}
        {% ifequal index_className index_tabLabel %}
            {% if index_className == 0 %}
                <li class="{{ item_className }} tabSel">{{ item_tabLabel }}</li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="{{ item_className }} tabUnsel">{{ item_tabLabel }}</li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endifequal %}
      {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is the answer to my question with my dictionary as is.  Thanks, I was going down the route of using `{$ with...` but couldn't quite get it.

Comment: Please note that this will work slower if you have many items in your list as it runs N^2 times.

Comment: My dictionaries are small (<10 items)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is with the way you are presenting your data.

Why don't you create your dictionary like this, where each key is the class name and the associated value is the label. It would be more semantic and readable.

```
'nav_dict': {
    'Chemical': 'Chemical!',
    'Avian': 'Avian!',
    'Mammal': 'Mammal!,
 }
```

Then you can just loop over this and place the key as the class attribute, and the value as the label attribute.

```
{% for key, value in nav_dict.items %}
    {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}
        <li class="{{ key }} tabSel">{{ value }}</li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="{{ key }} tabUnsel">{{ value }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If the order of the elements is important (as dictionaries are un-ordered), you could use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module to retain insertion order. You would do something like this inside your view...

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> nav_dict = OrderedDict(zip(['Chemical', 'Avian', 'Mamma!'], ['Chemical!', 'Avian!', 'Mammal!']))
OrderedDict([('Chemical', 'Chemical!'), ('Avian', 'Avian!'), ('Mammal', 'Mammal!')])
```

Similarly you could use a list of tuples as your data

```
'nav_list': [('Chemical', 'Chemical!'), ('Avian', 'Avian!'), ('Mammal', 'Mammal!')]
```

And loop over this object like so

```
{% for class_name, label_name in nav_list %}
    {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}
        <li class="{{ class_name }} tabSel">{{ label_name }}</li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="{{ class_name }} tabUnsel">{{ label_name }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you only want to append an exclamation mark to your string to create the label, you could of course create a custom template [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) instead - or just append the exclamation mark inside the template itself.

Comment: I had originally had my dictionary like that, but I need items in a specific order (not alphanumeric); that's why I choose to have a list as the dictionary value

Comment: Use a DefaultDict to retain the insertion order - I've added this to my answer hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer; the resulting template is cleaner than the answer I selected, but I need to keep my dictionary as is.

Comment: no worries. you can retain the order with an OrderedDict or a list of tuples like I showed and benefit from the cleaner markup